# What is Drive-initiated authorization?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

The ["About Authorizaion" page](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth) in Google Drive's SDK documentation has a section titled "Drive-initiated Authorization". Apparently, I can let Google Drive handle the auth flow for my app. How can I use or not use this?

Comment: Oh, so Drive actually initiates an authorization request every time the user opens or creates a file?

Comment: ...someone needs to rewrite the Drive docs. They're confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drive-initiated flow happens when your application integrates with the Drive UI and the user selects your application in the "Create New" or "Open With" menus.

Thanks for your feedback, we'll try to make this part of the documentation easier to understand.

Comment: so... how do I opt out of that flow, as the Docs suggest?

Comment: If you don't integrate with the Drive UI, you'll have to handle the oauth flow yourself